# Must solutions to the time-independent Schrodinger equation that have discrete or negative eigenvalues be square-integrable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces, sturm-liouville-theory

This is a very straightforward question (although the answer may not be!) about a ubiquitous textbook physics situation. I assume that the answer is probably well-known, but I asked it on both Math and Physics SE, and to my surprise, I got many upvotes but not a single answer.

Consider the following version of the time-independent Schrodinger equation:
$$
\left( -\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + V(x) \right) \psi(x) = \lambda\ \psi(x)
$$
(where we have absorbed some unimportant physical constants into the function $\psi(x)$). The function $V(x)$ is a given smooth function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which we assume to approach 0 at large arguments:
$$
\lim_{|x| \to \infty} V(x) = 0.
$$
The smooth complex-valued function $\psi:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ and the real constant $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ are to be determined. This equation is simply the eigenvalue equation for the linear second-order differential operator in parentheses. (We can loosen the smoothness requirements on $V(x)$ and $\psi(x)$, if doing so makes the problem more tractable.)

Non-rigorous physical heuristics suggest that these three statements are equivalent:

1. $\psi(x)$ is square-integrable, i.e. $$\int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx\ |\psi(x)|^2 < \infty,$$
2. $\lambda < 0$, and
3. $\lambda$ lies in a discrete part of the set of eigenvalues of the differential operator in parentheses, i.e. there exists a proper real interval such that $\lambda$ is the only eigenvalue of the differential operator that lies within that interval.

A related piece of "folk wisdom" considers the same eigenvalue equation in the case where
$$
\lim_{|x| \to \infty} V(x) = +\infty,
$$
and claims that in this case, (a) all eigenfunctions $\psi(x)$ must be square-integrable, and (b) the set of eigenvalues of the differential operator must be discrete.

But this "folk wisdom" is incorrect. [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/350394/92058) gives an explicit example of a function $V(x)$ and a square-integrable eigenfunction $\psi(x)$ with positive eigenvalue $\lambda$. Therefore, statement #1 above does not imply statement #2. (I do not know whether the eigenvalues for the particular differential operator given in that example are discrete or continuous around the relevant eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$, so I don't know the status of claim #3 for this example.)

What are the exact implications between the three statements above?
Of the six possible implications, which have been proven to be true, which (other than $1 \implies 2$) have explicit known counterexamples, and which are still open problems?

I'd also like to know about the case of multiple spatial dimensions, although I assume that the answers are probably the same as for the 1D case.

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/756599/2451

Answer (score 2):

(1) is perhaps better rephrased as: (1') $\lambda\in\sigma_p$ (in words: $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue) because then both (1') and (3) are statements about spectral properties. Also, in more compact notation, we can rewrite: (3) $\lambda\in\sigma_d$

As you pointed out, (1') $\implies$ (2) is false, and so is (1') $\implies$ (3), for the same reason. (2) $\implies$ (1') and (2) $\implies$ (3) are manifestly absurd.

(3) $\implies$ (2) is true because $V\to 0$ implies that $\sigma_{\textrm{ess}}=[0,\infty)$. (3) $\implies$ (1') is obvious since $\sigma_d\subseteq\sigma_p$.

Finally, indeed nothing changes in higher dimensions. A radially symmetric version of the von Neumann-Wigner potential still works as a counterexample to (1') $\implies\ldots$.

Comment: 1. Why is claim (1) equivalent to the claim that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue? It seems to me that any $\lambda$ must be an eigenvalue by definition, whether or not $\psi(x)$ is square-integrable.
2. What is "the reason" why (1') $\implies$ (2) is false? I just found one counterexample that satisfies claim (1) but not claim (2); I don't see how this tells us anything about claim (3).
3. Why are the propositions (2) $\implies$ (1') and (2) $\implies$ (3) "manifestly absurd"? Can you give a counterexample of a $V$, $\psi$, and $\lambda$ that satisfy (2) but not (1') or (3)?

Comment: @tparker "eigenvalue" is not the same as "spectrum". A value $\lambda$ is in the spectrum of the operator $T$ if $T-\lambda I$ doesn't have a bounded inverse; a value $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if $T-\lambda I$ is not injective. Returning to the Schrodinger operators, in the case $V\equiv 0$, any $\lambda \geq 0$ is in the spectrum but not an eigenvalue. // That (1') implies (2) is false is what you stated yourself in your question. // Regards to (3) it appears that Christian interpreted your statement (3) to mean that $\lambda$ is in the discrete part of the _spectrum_; ...

Comment: ... the specific example you mentioned has $\lambda$ an embedded eigenvalue: every interval around $\lambda$ intersect other parts of the spectrum, since the essential spectrum for that example includes all of $(0,\infty)$. But if your question is to be interpreted literally, as the statement that $\lambda$ is not a limit point of the set of eigenvalues, I am not sure what the answer should be for the class of Schrodinger operators you wrote down.

Comment: @WillieWong 1. Yes, I now understand the difference between eigenvalue and spectrum, and I have edited my question to remove any reference to the word "spectrum" to avoid ambiguity. As far as I know, in physics applications the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian are the relevant quantities, not the spectrum. 2. If $V \equiv 0$, then why isn't any $\lambda > 0$ an eigenvalue with eigenfunctions $\psi(x) = e^{\pm i \sqrt{\lambda} x}$? 3. So we still don't know whether (1) or (2) implies (3), or vice versa?

Comment: @tparker: An eigenvalue is, by definition, a $\lambda$ such that $H\psi=\lambda\psi$ (= your first displayed equation) has a solution from the domain of the operator $H$, so in particular $\psi\in L^2$. This will not hold for most $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. For example, if $V=0$, you can easily check that there are no eigenvalues.

Comment: @tparker: (2) as you stated cannot imply anything. Just because $\lambda < 0$ doesn't allow you to say anything about whether $\lambda$ belongs to the spectrum or not. Perhaps what you are thinking of is a statement along the lines of "$\lambda < 0$ and in the spectrum implies $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue", which is true in your setting.

Comment: @tparker: Both eigenvalues and spectrum are very relevant in physics (the spectrum is the set of possible energies of the system). May I suggest my functional analysis lecture notes, especially chapters 12, 13, if you want to seriously study some of the background (but it will be a major effort, as these depend on earlier chapters and especially the spectral theorem). Without this background, no meaningful discussion of the precise mathematics involved here is possible. They are available here: https://math.ou.edu/~cremling/teaching/ln.html

Comment: @ChristianRemling But I said in the OP that the domain of $H$ is the set of smooth functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, not $L^2$. At least, I meant to say that; I can edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Okay thanks, you may be right that I lack the mathematical background in functional analysis to usefully discuss this question.

Comment: @WillieWong As far as I know, the first equation in my question defines the set of eigenvalues, not the spectrum. (Correct?) My edited question has nothing at all do with the spectrum of the Hamiltonian; I only care about the set of eigenvalues $\lambda$. Any discussion of the spectrum seems extraneous.

Comment: @tparker: My answer is still valid (almost) literally even after your edits. The only extra thing one needs is that their are upgrades of the vN-W potential with a dense in $(0,\infty)$ set of eigenvalues and still $V\to 0$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling So do you have an explicit counterexample that satisfies (2) but violates (1') and (3)?